# Smalltalk-80 character meaning/usage

Tags: smalltalk

What is the exact meaning of these characters **←, ≡, ¬, ≠, ⌾,** and **∢** and how are used in Smalltalk-80?

consider the following expressions: (taken from the smalltalk-80 source code)

1. `^self class ≡ x ≡ false`
2. `^mem ◦ ¬448 ≠ 0`
3. `strm frame ← 15000 ⌾ frame origin y rect: 20000 ⌾ frame corner y.`
4. `neg ← (aStream ∢ 45 "-" ifTrue: [true] ifFalse: [aStream ∢ 21 "**¬**"]).`

Note: This examples were extracted from the original Xerox Alto disks found in this link: http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/bits/Xerox/Alto/disk_images/

Comment: $⌾ looks like the old version of the current $@ for Point formation x@y.
$∢ seems to be reading the next character of aStream and answering with its code point (note that 45 is the ASCII of $-.

Comment: $≡ seems the old version for the current #== and $≠ for $~=.

Comment: Could you provide a reference to the source. for those characters? As far as I can tell from looking at page 82 of [this](http://stephane.ducasse.free.fr/FreeBooks/TheInteractiveProgrammingEnv/TheInteractiveProgrammingEnv.pdf) the only non-ASCII characters are the left arrow and the up arrow.

Comment: That seems to be a curious mix of Smalltalk-76/78 and Smalltalk-80. Where did you find in?

Comment: i updated the question with the sources link for you to take a look, you'll need a tool to extract the .dsk files.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia I would say that ∢ is an eye: so it is a lookup for an object in the stream (peekFor:), it answers true if next char code is 45. If true, it advance the stream to next position.

Comment: @aka.nice Yes!!! you peeked it further than me, ha!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like this is a source file from a Xerox-internal version of Smalltalk-80. For the public release they must have replaced these "unusual" chars (which required custom font glyphs) with ASCII, only keeping `←` and `↑` glyphs for the `_` and `^` ASCII characters.

This is a best guess based on my experience with St76/78 (Update: confirmed by Dan Ingalls):

1. `←` assignment as in `var ← object`. Same in St80.
2. `rcvr word← arg` is an alternative to `word:` and usually indicates assignment to a slot of the receiver (e.g. `x←` as in `point x ← 100`). St80 only allows keywords ending in a colon `:`.

   The parser treats `←` as lower precedence so you can have keyword expressions on both sides of it. E.g.

   `a foo: b ← c bar: d`

   would eval `c bar: d` and pass the result as second argument to a's `foo:←` method).
3. `◦` indexing as in `array◦index`. St80 uses `at:` instead.
4. `◦←` equivalent to St80's `at:put:` as in `array◦index ← value`
5. `≡` identity, like St80's `==`
6. `¬` literal for negative numbers as in `¬1` for -1. The parser treated `-` as a binary message selector so another symbol had to be used for negative numbers literals.
7. `≠` not equal, like St80's `~=`
8. `≢` not identical, like St80's `~~`
9. `⌾` create a Point, like St80's `@`
10. `∢` match token from stream. If the next token read from stream matches the argument, it is consumed and returned. Otherwise it answers `false`.

For more info check out the [Smalltalk Zoo](https://smalltalkzoo.thechm.org/) website.

Comment: This is cool. I have read a lot *about* Smalltalk-72–78 but have never actually read anything other than Smalltalk-80 and beyond (Self, Newspeak, Strongtalk, etc.)

Comment: I sent this to Dan Ingalls who confirmed this is correct.